# Changing binding property type from string to int

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, converters

I'm trying to change the binding property of several columns from string to int since they are being read from a file and I want to use numeric sort when the data is finally displayed on screen.

I created this converter and made the corresponding changes in the XAML file to implement the converter in the `DataTemplate` tag but I am still getting string sort in my output, not numeric sort.

I looked around for other versions of a similar converter but didn't find anything relevant. I'm unsure of what the problem with my converter is.

Here is my converter:

```
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string s = (string)value;
            int num;
            if (int.TryParse(s, out num))
                return num;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int number = (int)value;
        return number.ToString();
    }
}
```

And these are the changes made in the `XAML`. The local `namespace` is defined in `Windows.Resources`.

```
<me:IntToStringConverter x:Key="IntToStringConverter" />
```

The sorting part looks like this:

```
<toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="55" Header="Min Run" SortMemberPath="MinRun">
    <toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Path=MinRun, Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</toolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

`DataGrid` is bound here:

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="myGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" ItemsSource="{Binding ObsRacResults}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" BorderThickness="0" Margin="4" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF555555" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF555555" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" CanUserResizeRows="False">
```

and then I have my columns, styles etc.

Comment: Where are you trying to sort? could you provide that code?

Comment: I think once it is in TextBlock it thinks the data as string.

Comment: hmmm.  What could I change it to?

Comment: Where DataGrid is bound?